# Editar o 'style' da tag 'div' externa de uma box no Shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny

Estou desenvolvendo um app no Shiny do R, e estou com problema para editar a tag de fora de uma box.

Quando eu rodo o comando:

```
box(
  title = 'Teste',
  width = 4
)
```

o HTML correspondente que ele cria é:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-header">
      <h3 class="box-title">Teste</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Existe o parâmetro `style` na `box()`, porém ele altera somente a classe `"box-body"` e eu queria alterar a classe `"col-sm-4"` sem ter que inputar o HTML no meu código, tem como?

---

Por exemplo, se eu rodo:

```
box(
  title = 'Teste',
  width = 4,
  style = 'padding-left: 0px;'
)
```

Ele gera:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-header">
      <h3 class="box-title">Teste</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body" style="padding-left: 0px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Mas eu quero:

```
<div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left: 0px">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-header">
      <h3 class="box-title">Teste</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: acho que você precisa dar um ' . ' na classe, apenas isso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui achar uma solução.

Quando eu crio a box com `width = NULL` ela não vem dentro de uma div, então consigo eu mesmo criar a div (no R é o `column()`), porém fica com uma div a mais.

Por exemplo:

```
box(
  title = 'Teste',
  width = NULL
)
```

se transforma em

```
<div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-header">
      <h3 class="box-title">A</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Então se faço:

```
column(
  width = 4, style='padding-left: 0px;',
  box(
    title = 'A',
    width = NULL
  )
)
```

tenho

```
<div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
  <div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-header">
        <h3 class="box-title">A</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="box-body"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei como é no Shiny mas no css
seria

```
.box {

  width : 4px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

não sei se ajuda.

Comment: No caso, seria a classe .col-sm-4 mais aí mudariam todas com esse nome. Fiz uns testes aqui e acabei conseguindo achar uma solução no próprio shiny.